# Как получить iOS9 beta и El Capitan официально ?

Tags: apple

Слышал нужно регистрироваться как разработчик?
Как это сделать? 
Сколько стоит?
Придется ждать одобрения? Сколько?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что с такими вопросами нужно обращаться к Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До выхода El Capitan & iOS 9 для получения бета версий (за исключением Yosemite) было необходимо зарегистрироваться с apple как разработчик и это стоит $99 в год. С выходом последних бета версий телефонной и компьютерой операционных систем вы можете попробовать обе просто пройдя по ссылке

https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/

и войдя используя свой apple ID принять участие в их бета программе. На сегодняшний день стабильным релизом является 9 beta 4. Если все же вам нужно больше, то зарегистрировшись как разработчик вы можете получить доступ к iOS 9 beta 5 pre-release.

Comment: Получилось, антон jk Спасибо! Отметил